# Update set con Inner Join

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tratando de actualizar un campo de una tabla pero debo relacionar otras tablas como referencias para poder hacer la actualización. Tengo el siguiente query:

```
update proddta.F76C0101
set V0EFDJ = 150365
where trim(V076CTAX) in (select a.V0EFDJ fecfin from proddta.F76C0101 a
inner join proddta.F0101 b on a.V0AN8 = b.ABAN8
where  a.V0EFDJ <= '121001' and b.ABSBLI = ' ' and trim(a.V076CTAX) = '890.903.055-1');
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error SQL: ORA-01722: número no válido

Este campo es una fecha Juliana, la fecha gregoriana es el 31/12/2050, convertida a Juliana. Pero me sigue saliendo ese error

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque la actualizas como numero, y abajo la tratas como un string? es un numero o un string?

Comment: Cómo está definida la tabla destino (tipos de dato de las columnas)? Qué versión de Oracle?